# How to use Android Built-in Alarm to integrate my alarm app?

Tags: android, alarm

I want to create my alarm app.
but, I don't want to re-design a new alarm clock function.
so, I want to use android built-in alarm clock.

what I want the procedure is:

1. use android built-in alarm clock to set the time.
2. when the alarm is ring, my alarm app will be launched to replace built-in one.
3. use my alarm app to dismiss the alarm.

How could I make it?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Your application would have to be running, listening for an Alarm, or something along those lines

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523350/android-alarm-clock-ui

Answer (score 0):

> How could I make it?

You can't. The only thing an SDK app can do with respect to the device's own alarm clock app is to display an activity to allow the user to set the alarm, with a filled-in set of values.